# Given a flight route specified with one or several flight numbers, how can I see how their price changes throughout the year?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, online-resources

Given a flight route specified with one or several flight numbers, how can I see how the price changes throughout the year? I.e., from today, see how the price of the route changes from day to day. I couldn't find a way to do so on Google Flights, aside from manually trying different days, which is tedious.

E.g., the following graph for UA 2604:

[image]

(plot is made up)

Answer (score 1):

Can be done on [ITA Matrix](https://matrix.itasoftware.com/), Prices for UA2604 in March. Prices vary between $44 and $174, i.e. almost by a factor of 4.

[image]

Of course, this depends on whether it's a one-way or part of a round trip, basic vs regular, advanced booking time, bags, and many other potential variables.

Here is the query

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What search do you do to get an overview for the entire month?  On my side, using https://matrix.itasoftware.com/, I see https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRS4G.png -> can't do more than +/-2 days.

Comment: I added the query, Just select "see calendar of lowest fares"

Comment: got it, thanks, I shouldn't have used dark mode (dropdown arrow invisible).